# PDO - can both CREATE and DROP statements be in the same query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, pdo, create-table, drop-table

I have SQL code that executes `CREATE TABLE` and `DROP TABLE` in the same query. When I run it, it prints `bool(false)` meaning error. Can it be done in one query?

```
$dbh = new PDO("sqlite::memory:");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("create table a ( i int, j int);drop table a");
var_dump($stmt);
```

---

I don't know why but it works if I try it again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute your query
Like this :
$stmt ->execute();

And yes you can create and delete a table in the same query.

You can maybe try this to catch an error, it will help you 

    `try
    {
        $db = new PDO('sqlite::memory'); 
        echo "SQLite created in memory."; 
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    }`

Comment: I can't `execute()` it because `prepare` returns false.

Comment: For me add $stmt->execute() did u try it ?